# Showing entries in CP only for specific category

Tags: structure, category, sorting

I need to sort structure section entries belonging to specific category (entries have category field).

With default structure list displayed in CP, i see all entries for this structure type section thrown in together. This makes sorting cumbersome because if i want to sort inside specific categpry, all other entries from other categories are in the way.

So, can i display entries only related to specific category in CP?